# Pulling a List of Values from a Map given a List of Keys on Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I feel embarrassed that I am stuck on this but I am trying to pull the List of Strings (`List<String>`) from the `Map<MyEnum, String>` given then List of enum keys `List<MyEnum>`.  The `List<MyEnum>` may or may not contain entries.

Edit:

```
List<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();

for (MyEnum field : fields) {
    String value = null;
    if ((value = map.get(field)) != null) {
       toReturn.add(value);
    }
}
return toReturn;
```

But I am looking for a Java 8 way to do this.  Such as...

```
map.stream().map(e->?????)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code on which you are "stuck", as well as what about it you are "stuck" on.  Just saying "stuck" doesn't really mean much to us.

Comment: Does it have to be done with a Stream?  `Map<MyEnum, String> copy = new HashMap<>(map); copy.keySet().retainAll(fields); toReturn = new ArrayList<>(copy.values());` would probably be cleaner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fields.stream()
      .map(map::get)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```